# grid dont work with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

supposed to divide a row of two, but showing two rows, this is the code...
im using the bootstrap v3.1.1 and the tutorial that i see use bootstrap V3 be diferent?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>probando</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">

    <p>probando nuevas cosas</p>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
            <h1>Debe estar mas resaltado</h1>

            <p>proabando con mas palbras pra ver que pasa</p>
            </div>

            <div class="span6">
            <h1>Debe estar mas resaltado</h1>

            <p>proabando con mas palbras pra ver que pasa</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 3 onward the grid classes have changed. Now they are specific to each viewport (desktop, tablet, mobile) and start with `col-xs-*` (for large screen), `col-md-*` (for medium screen) etc. More info [here.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your trying v2 in v3 to me. span6 is outdated.

Should be something like this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Debe estar mas resaltado</h1>
      <p>proabando con mas palbras pra ver que pasa</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Debe estar mas resaltado</h1>
      <p>proabando con mas palbras pra ver que pasa</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Finaly...one small thing (I guess you already added),
I haven't see bootstrap js and viewport code in your code here. So just in case you forgot to add, you'll have to add something like this in your header...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Your classes should be "col-xs-6" see the bootstrap documentation - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1):

`span6` indicates that your tutorial is for the now-pretty-outdated Bootstrap v2, which isn't compatible with v3. Find yourself a newer tutorial. Or, ya know, just read the official docs; they're very thorough and give tons of examples.  :-)